# Is there a way to mark only one test to run?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm debugging one test which fails. Is there a way to mark only one test to run?

something like:

```
@pytest.only # it doesn't work
def test_some_test():
  ...
```

Comment: My question is different. I know about the pattern filtering. But it is clumsy. `only` exists mostly everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark your test with `pytest.mark`. The mark is dynamically created, so you can choose almost any name. [Here is a link to docs.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html)

For example in `tt.py`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.one_test
def test_foo():
    assert 1 == 1

def test_bar():
    assert 2 == 2

enter code here
```

and then run with `pytest tt.py -m one_test` :

```
pytest tt.py -m one_test

======================= test session starts =========================

platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.6.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0

rootdir: /Users/foobarna/workspace/random, inifile:
collected 2 items / 1 deselected

tt.py .
[100%]

============= 1 passed, 1 deselected in 0.04 seconds ================
```